# Web Audio API: Safari (iOS and macOS) crash when Channel Merger connected to Biquad Filter

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

This minimal example crashes Safari after the audio stops playing:

```
<script>
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function start () {
  var source = context.createOscillator();
  var chanMerge = context.createChannelMerger(2);
  var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

  source.connect(chanMerge, 0, 0);
  source.connect(chanMerge, 0, 1);
  // Connecting the channel merger directly to
  // the biquad filter seems to be the problem.
  chanMerge.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(context.destination);

  source.start(0);
  source.stop(2); // This triggers the crash.
}
</script>
<p>Safari will crash on/before the end of the tone</p>
<button onclick='start()'>Play then crash</button>
```

On the desktop (Version 10.1), it generates the following crash report: https://gist.github.com/captbaritone/f27385b454ecdaf8174a921604524412

Answer (score 1):

I've found a temporary workaround. It's possible to insert a dummy node in between the merger and the biquad filter. So the following example, seems to work:

```
<script>
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function start () {
  var source = context.createOscillator();
  var chanMerge = context.createChannelMerger(2);
  var filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
  var dummyAnalyser = context.createAnalyser();

  source.connect(chanMerge, 0, 0);
  source.connect(chanMerge, 0, 1);

  chanMerge.connect(dummyAnalyser);

  // Introducing this indirection seems to resolve the issue.
  dummyAnalyser.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(context.destination);

  source.start(0);
  source.stop(2); // This triggers the crash.
}
</script>
<p>Safari will crash on/before the end of the tone</p>
<button onclick='start()'>Play then crash</button>
```